# Axios impossible to read 403 answer body

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to use Vue + axios to query the N26 bank API. To do so you need to ask for a MFA token and go through MFA authorization. The first step is to get the MFA token, by querying https://api.tech26.global/oauth2/token/ and they reply with a 403 with the token in the data. It works when I curl :

```sh
% curl -i -H "Authorization: Basic bmF0aXZld2ViOg==" -H  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "device-token: aDeviceToken"  https://api.tech26.global/oauth2/token --data "username=myUsername&password=MyPassword&grant_type=password"
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
{"userMessage":{"title":"A second authentication factor is required.","detail":"Please provide your second form of authentication."},"mfaToken":"mfaToken","error_description":"MFA token is required","detail":"MFA token is required","hostUrl":"https://api.tech26.global","type":"mfa_required","error":"mfa_required","title":"A second authentication factor is required.","message":"Please provide your second form of authentication.","userId":"MyUserID","status":403}
```

As you can see, the MFA token is in the answer and can be used to continue the workflow.
However when doing so with Axios on Vue.js, It is impossible for me the get the message with the 403 reply:

```json
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append('grant_type', 'password');
data.append('username', 'myUserName');
data.append('password', 'MyPassword');
let headers = { "Authorization": "Basic bmF0aXZld2ViOg==", "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "device-token": "MyDeviceToken" };
let response = await axios.post(`https://api.tech26.global/oauth2/token`, data, { headers });
console.log(response)
```

But the only thing in the logs is "XHR OPTIONS [https://api.tech26.global/oauth2/token"](https://api.tech26.global/oauth2/token%22), and when I click on it it just shows 403, without the response body. I tried looking for a way to retrieve the 403 body message, but nobody seems to be interested in this (and it is quite weird that they reply with 403 when this is the normal workflow). Does anyone know how to fetch the response body with axios please ?

Comment: If you use `await` with axios, you need to try/catch the AxiosError and can then access the response object on the error object `error.response`.

Comment: Axios won't resolve the promise in case of a status error code (e.g. `4xx` or `5xx`).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 console.log(error.response) returns undefined.
Does that mean that I cannot use axios for this ?

Comment: Use `try { const successResponse = await axios.post(); } catch (error) { console.log(error.response); }`

Comment: This is what I did, and it returns undefined.
```json
try {
        let response = await axios.post(`${N26.apiUrl}/oauth2/token`, data, { headers });
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.response)
        }
```

Comment: And the response in the try block is also undefined? Or can you check the status code of the response?

Comment: It is also undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a CORS problem.

The `OPTIONS` message is the [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) the browser automatically sends (because you have a custom header: `device-token`) *before* it can proceed with the `POST`. Since the preflight failed with 403, the `POST` request is not actually sent to the server.

You'll need another way to get the `mfaToken`, and that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. I used a Golang implementation of these requests as a source, and tried to do it with js. Since it is impossible, I will go back to use Golang to get the mfaToken.